# how to make connection from node js to python?

Tags: python, node.js

I am new to node js and python just i want to communicate node js to python and vice versa. I need simple script that runs and host on web browser to get executed python script in node js. Just wan to transfer one message from node js to python using after running node js script with hosted envirnoment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute python code from  nodejs using system call.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'python myscript.py';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  // command output is in stdout (This the output from the python script that you might use
});
```

Comment: from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8085)

Comment: Above one is script from that how should i call to node js?

Comment: Save this code to file like run.py or main.py var cmd = 'python main.py or run.py'; give the absolute file path

Comment: Do you want the output ? Like running on port 8085 ? or you just want to start the bottle server ?

Comment: Yes i want running on port which gives an python url

Comment: Just i want to print python script after running node js

Comment: then use the stdout var this should contain the command line message

Comment: var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('python',['do.py']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

Comment: var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').spawn,
    run  = exec('/usr/bin/python', ['-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '9000']);

run.stdout.on('data', function(data){ 
   console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

run.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});  Try this code

Comment: Its not working, python url should hit node js url after running node js

Comment: from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=9001)

Comment: var util = require('util'); 
var exec = require('child_process').spawn; 
var run = exec('/usr/bin/python', ['-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '9002']); 
run.stdout.on('data', function(data){ 
 console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString()); 
 }); 
run.stderr.on('data', function (data) { 
 console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString()); 
 });

Comment: If i run node js code it should hit python url in the consol. Is this possible?